# error calling method class with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, class, pyspark

I am using notebook to create an AnomalyMount class. So far I haven't developed a lot of method. I am using another script as the main program. I instantiated an object of the AnomalieMontage class then I tried to call the AM_skipnewline method I have this error message.
My class:

```
class AnomalieMontage:
    def AM_skipnewline(self,df):
        self.new_colum_name=[self.e.replace("\n","") for self.e in self.df.columns]
        self.original_colum_name=self.df.columns
        for self.e,self.j in zip(self.original_colum_name,self.new_colum_name):
            self.df=self.df.withColumnRenamed(e, j)
```

My main programm:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.AM_DEV_ENR import *
from os import listdir
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl
import findspark
findspark.init()
print("ok")
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext as sqlContext
import xlrd
#from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from com.crealytics.spark.excel import *

#spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.0").getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.5").getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled" , "true" )
            return df

test=AnomalieMontage()
df=test.AM_skipnewline(df)
```

I get this error message. I don't see what's wrong with this code:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_22468/1532015928.py in <module>
      1 test=AnomalieMontage()
----> 2 df=test.AM_skipnewline(df)

~\EM_DEV_PYSPARK\AM_DEV_ENR.ipynb in AM_skipnewline(self, df)
      6    "id": "94c13422",
      7    "metadata": {},
----> 8    "outputs": [],
      9    "source": [
     10     "class AnomalieMontage:\n",

AttributeError: 'AnomalieMontage' object has no attribute 'df'
```

Comment: Please add the _whole_ definition for the `AnomalieMontage` class.

Comment: Some of the `self.df` should presumably be `df`, to access the method parameter.

Comment: what do mean by whole definition for AnomalieMontage class

Comment: share init function

Comment: I don't have any function inialisation. I am using the default constructor